# Threejs: How to create a multiple parametric objects in a scene? Each parametric objects must have different dimension

Tags: typescript, three.js, singleton

I'm using ThreeJS to develop a web application that displays custom parametric items in the scene. I have written a custom class to create a shape as THREE.Shape() and THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(). I have implemented in Singleton class in typescript. I wanted to implement this with multiple items in the scene.

```
    let pushedVariables: Array<NumberVariable> = [];
    designJson['variables'].forEach((jsonVariable: any) =>{
    let variable: NumberVariable | null =         parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable(jsonVariable.name);
    
        if(variable && IGNORED_VARIABLES.indexOf(variable.name) < 0){
            let min: number = Math.round(jsonVariable.min * 100) / 100;
            let max: number = Math.round(jsonVariable.max * 100) / 100;
            let value: number = Math.round(jsonVariable.value * 100) / 100;
            variable.setMinPassive(min);
            variable.setMaxPassive(max);
            variable.setValuePassive(value);
            pushedVariables.push(variable);  
        }
    });
        pushedVariables.forEach((variable: NumberVariable) => {
            console.log(variable)
            variable.min = variable.min;
            variable.max = variable.max;
            variable.value = variable.value;                                        
        });
    let box = new Box3().setFromObject(physicalParametricItem);
    let size = box.getSize(new Vector3());
    box.getCenter( physicalParametricItem.position ); 
    physicalParametricItem.position.multiplyScalar( - 1 );

    var pivot = new Group();
    const axesHelper = new AxesHelper( 2000 );
    pivot.add( physicalParametricItem );
    scene.add( pivot );

    let boxhelper = new LineSegments(new EdgesGeometry(new BoxGeometry(size.x, size.y, size.z)),boxHelperMaterial);
    pivot.add(boxhelper);
```

the problem is, I try to adjust the size as (width, height, depth) and it will not be resizing based on updated values.

```
let width: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('width');
gui.add(width, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe Width').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);

let height: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('height');
gui.add(height, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe Height').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);

let depth: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('depth');
gui.add(depth, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe depth').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);

function updateBoundingBoxUpdate(){
    let box2 = new Box3().setFromObject(physicalParametricItem);
    let size2 = parametricItem._size;
    boxhelper.geometry = new EdgesGeometry(new BoxGeometry(size2.x, size2.y, size2.z));
    let offset = size2.clone().negate().multiplyScalar(0.5);
    physicalParametricItem.position.set(offset.x,offset.y,offset.z);
}
```

demo of the current code base
https://www.loom.com/share/fd014e4f540c45038452955d41f7013b?sid=19b18a07-cbcf-46eb-a8a2-4759c46dd095

I need a help in creating multiple objects with different dimensions in a scene.

Thanks. :)